# previous entered message is coming in text area

Tags: apex

Click on submit FeedBack link and Pop up box open and entered text and click on cancel.again click on submit FeedBack link. but previous entered message is coming in text area. It should not be present there.
..
Controller

```
public void openPopUp()
    {

        Hide=true;
    }

    public void showSubmit()
    {
        Hide=true;
        showSub=true;

    }
    public void closePopup()
    {
        ShowMsg=false;
        Hide=false;
    }


    public PageReference Submit()
    {
        Feedback__c objFB=new Feedback__c(Description__c=Feedback);
        insert objFB;
        Hide=false;
        ShowMsg=true;
        Feedback=null;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you supply the VisualForce page as well?

Comment: I created VFcomponent , not VF page.

Comment: chek if you are setting something by default for your inputtext/ inputfield values

Comment: <apex:outputPanel id="enablebtn">
                            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!Submit}" reRender="msg,popup" disabled="{!OR(ISBLANK(Feedback), '' == Feedback)}" id="theButton"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                         </apex:outputPanel>
                            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" reRender="popup" rendered="{!Hide}"/>
                            </center>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

Comment: @user10584 please update your question and post the VF page

Comment: I am using VF component , not VF page.

Comment: Click on submit FeedBack link and Pop up box opened and I entered text and click on cancel button.again click on submit FeedBack link. but previous entered message is coming in text area. It should not be present there.It should return blank text area for new pop up box op when user open again.

Comment: <apex:outputPanel id="enablebtn">
                            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!Submit}" reRender="msg,popup" disabled="{!OR(ISBLANK(Feedback), '' == Feedback)}" id="theButton"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                         </apex:outputPanel>
                            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" reRender="popup" rendered="{!Hide}"/>
                            </center>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

Comment: <apex:actionRegion >
                              <apex:outputLabel style="margin-left:-79%">Submit Feedback</apex:outputLabel><br/>
                              <apex:actionFunction name="testfeedback" reRender="enablebtn"/>
                              <apex:inputTextarea value="{!Feedback}" onkeyup="testfeedback()" style="width:100%;Height:200px;resize:none"/>  
                          </apex:actionRegion>

Comment: user10584 -- please use the Edit button underneath your original post and add these VF code snippets to the original post - they are too hard to decipher as comments